# Strapi v4 PostgreSQL connection from local project to azure db

Tags: postgresql, azure, strapi

Trying to connect to an Azure PostgreSQL server from my local Strapi project (eventually deployed in a docker container).

I have the connection configured according to the strapi docs, including using the cert downloaded from the azure portal:

`https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/configurations/required/databases.html#configuration-structure`

my database.js file:

```
// PostgreSQL
////////////////////////////////////////

const fs = require("@strapi/strapi/lib/services/fs");

const parse = require("pg-connection-string").parse;
const db = parse("azure-conn-string");

module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  connection: {
    client: "postgres",
    connection: {
      host: db.host,
      port: db.port,
      database: db.database,
      user: db.user,
      password: db.password,
      ssl: {
        ca: fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/db.crt.pem`).toString(),
      },
    },
  },
});
```

when starting the server i get this in the terminal:

```
error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "ip-address", user "username", database "db_name", SSL off
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/Users/x/x/dockertest/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98)
    at Parser.handlePacket (/Users/x/x/dockertest/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/x/x/dockertest/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/x/x/dockertest/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at Socket.emit (domain.js:475:12)
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:293:12)
    at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:267:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:206:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)
```

It seems like its trying to connect with ssl off, I'm not sure why since it should be configured to be enabled. If I remove the ssl rule from the azure database, the connection will go through so it seems like the problem is something with the ssl config.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

```
   module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  defaultConnection: "default",
  connection: {
    client: "postgres",
    connection: {
      host: env("DATABASE_HOST", "localhost"),
      port: env.int("DATABASE_PORT", 5432),
      database: env("DATABASE_NAME", "postgres"),
      user: env("DATABASE_USER", "postgres"),
      password: env("DATABASE_PASSWORD", "0000"),
      schema: env("DATABASE_SCHEMA", "public"),
    },
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.